# Chaining Multiple Map-Reduce jobs using Mincemeat.py

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mapreduce, information-retrieval

I am trying to work out a large program using Map-Reduce framework which needs the entire process be split into three Map-Reduce jobs which should happen sequentially.

I am using [mincemeat.py](https://github.com/michaelfairley/mincemeatpy) because I read in many places that it is faster than octo.py and other framework implementations in python.

But I am not able to chain the multiple jobs because each client needs to give a password and get connected to server for execution. My idea is that by starting client all the jobs should run in sequence. I am a newbie in python. Appreciate if someone can help me in this regard.

Below is the code that starts a job, for example wordCount here..

```
s = mincemeat.Server()
s.datasource = datasource
s.mapfn = map_wordCount
s.reducefn = reduce_wordCount
wordCounts = s.run_server(password="password")
print wordCounts
```

I want another job's map and reduce functions to be called without the requirement for a separate client invocation of it. Anyone with pointers to how this can be done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just not use `map` for a `Pool` of workers that will launch a batch of jobs whose goal is to launch another `Pool` of workers each running `map`-reduce jobs?  I never heard of `mincemeat.py`, but I do this with the `pathos` framework… which provides a `Pool` with a blocking `map`, iterative `imap`, and asynchronous `amap` (as well as `pipes`) for backends such as `multiprocessing`, `threading`, `mpi4py`, `parallel python` (socket-based distributed parallel computing), and ssh-tunneling.

This has the overhead of whatever backend or backends you choose, so for very small tasks you see a good bit of the time as overhead, but for anything larger the nested distributed parallel computing is a win.

You can find `pathos` (and `pyina` -- the `mpi4py` portion of `pathos`) here: https://github.com/uqfoundation